# массовая замена в mysql

Tags: mysql

и так, есть таблица, содержащая, например, логи(не обязательно их). в таблице больше 50000 значений в формате www.examle.com DD.MM.YYYY HH:MI:SS, соответственно, каждая строка уникальна. Как можно разумным количеством запросов изменить www.example.com на www.new-example.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName SET columnName =
   REPLACE( columnName, 'www.example.com', 'www.new-example.com' )
```

Comment: для чего два раза имя столбца указано?

Comment: 1 - какое поле таблицы нужно обновить; 2 - в функцию `REPLACE` передаем текущее значение поля и что на что нужно заменить

Comment: ну ведь они всегда совпадают получается?

Comment: @Дмитрий Не обязательно, ведь вдруг вы захотите заменить одно поле значением из другого: `UPDATE tableName SET columnName = secondColumnName` ( в данном примере без изменения типа REPLACE )